# ASP.NET MVC 3.0 use the best URL

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, url-routing, asp.net-mvc-routing, seo

If you create a new asp.net mvc website the default routing in `Global.asax.cs` is as follows:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                "Default", // Route name
                "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
                new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
            );

        }
```

This means that the following urls all resolve to the same page.

- mysite.com
- mysite.com/home
- mysite.com/home/index

If anyone hits `mysite.com/home` or `mysite.com/home/index` I want the url to be `mysite.com`. This is the best url for it. Also it would mean that Google and other search engines don'think I have duplicate content.

How would I do this?

Answer (score 0):

you could try two options:

1. Check out [here](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ASPNETMVCAndTheNewIIS7RewriteModule.aspx) for how to create URL rewrite rule.
2. You can also call for

   ```
    context.Response.RedirectPermanently("mysite.com"); // you can do this in custom httphandler
   ```

If anyone hits mysite.com/home or mysite.com/home/index

not sure if this solves your Google search engine content duplicate.

Comment: The problems outlined in you answer would be that it is not automatically extensible. If I add a block controller. And add a block index id then I will get /blog and /blog/index. I will need to manually add a rewrite rule. I would like it to happen automatically.

Comment: @Will: so you will have "Index" action method in each controller? I just want to make sure that only controller name is changing in your case. Not the action name?

Answer (score 0):

This answer isn't specific to ASP.NET MVC, as you can use this on any page to confirm the correct canonical page for the content... for example, if you visit

```
www.stevefenton.co.uk/Content/Home/
```

You will see the following element in the head of the document...

```
<link rel="canonical" href="http://www.stevefenton.co.uk/">
```

This confirms to web crawlers that the master address for the page is in fact the root page.

To make this specific to your ASP.NET MVC page, your best bet is to ensure you always link to the correct variant of your address, so all links point to the correct place. Web crawlers follow your links (as do your users) so if your links are correct, they will index the content for those links.